# flutter fix tabbar in top of screen when i scroll the view

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

like with `Instagram` in profile page of that, i want to fix `Tabbar` on top of screen when i scroll the view, for example:

[image]

i think i should implementing that with `SliverAppBar`, this is my code, but it doesn't work correctly and in that top of tab elements will be change height

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController _tabController;
  ScrollController _scrollViewController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: 2);
    _scrollViewController = ScrollController(initialScrollOffset: 0.0);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    _scrollViewController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: NestedScrollView(
        controller: _scrollViewController,
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool boxIsScrolled) {
          return <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
              title: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    height: 200.0,
                    color: Colors.green,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 200.0,
                    color: Colors.yellow,
                  ),

                ],
              ),
              pinned: true,
              floating: true,
              forceElevated: boxIsScrolled,
              bottom: TabBar(
                tabs: <Widget>[
                  Tab(
                    text: "Home",
                    icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                  ),
                  Tab(
                    text: "Example page",
                    icon: Icon(Icons.help),
                  )
                ],
                controller: _tabController,
              ),
            )
          ];
        },
        body: TabBarView(
          children: <Widget>[
            PageOne(),
            PageTwo(),
          ],
          controller: _tabController,
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.control_point),
        onPressed: () {
          _tabController.animateTo(1,
              curve: Curves.bounceInOut, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 10));

          // _scrollViewController.animateTo(
          //     _scrollViewController.position.minScrollExtent,
          //     duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
          //     curve: Curves.decelerate);

          _scrollViewController
              .jumpTo(_scrollViewController.position.maxScrollExtent);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PageOne extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Image.asset(
            'assets/photos/wallpaper-1.jpg',
            width: 200.0,
          ),
          Image.asset(
            'assets/photos/wallpaper-2.jpg',
            width: 200.0,
          ),
          Image.asset(
            'assets/photos/wallpaper-3.jpg',
            width: 200.0,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PageTwo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemExtent: 250.0,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Material(
          elevation: 4.0,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
          color: index % 2 == 0 ? Colors.cyan : Colors.deepOrange,
          child: Center(
            child: Text(index.toString()),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Popo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
      body: SafeArea(
        child: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
              title: Container(
                color: Colors.grey[100],
                height: 200,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    "Head",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SliverAppBar(
              pinned: true,
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              title: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Icon(
                    Icons.dashboard
                  ),
                  Icon(
                      Icons.tv
                  ),
                  Icon(
                      Icons.person
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SliverAnimatedList(
              itemBuilder: (_, index, ___){
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(index.toString()),
                );
              },
              initialItemCount: 100,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The ouput:

[image]

Comment: @`Josteve Adekanbi` thanks a lot, how can customize `SliverAppBar`? like with instagram i have more `Column` here

Comment: Could you do as you wish? I have to do tabbar like Instagram. @DolDurma

Comment: @AlperenARICI yes, you can test this sample and that works as well

Comment: yes thank you, this works, but I do not exactly that, like in instagram, the menu below shifts to the right and left.
I want. @DolDurma

Comment: @AlperenARICI your mean is bottomNavigation menus?

Comment: @DolDurma No, I want to do it from the IG Tv, photos etc. menu that slides right and left in the profile section of Instagram. When that menu scrolls down, it stays fixed, just like in Instagram above, and I can switch left and right over it.As you show in the example.