# TapBar on scroll down Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

please help. I want the TabBar to stick to the top of the screen when scrolling down.
I want to do something like the picture below:

[image]
[image]

Comment: check this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60856012/flutter-fix-tabbar-in-top-of-screen-when-i-scroll-the-view

Answer (score 0):

You can use SilverAppBar Widget, refer to the below implementation.

```
class MyStickyBar extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: CustomScrollView(
            slivers: <Widget>[
              SliverAppBar(
                title: Text('StickyBar'),
                // Making menu bar sticky
                floating: true,
                // Sets menu bar to the top of screen
                snap: true,
                backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                bottom: PreferredSize(
                  preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(48),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                        onPressed: () {},
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                        onPressed: () {},
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
                        onPressed: () {},
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              // Adding a scrollable list below sticky menu bar
              SliverList(
                delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                  (context, index) {
                    return ListTile(title: Text('Item $index'));
                  },
                  childCount: 50,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```